# Leaflet library not found

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, leaflet

I've decided to add interactive maps to my website and Leaflet module seems to provide mobile-friendly maps. I followed the installation steps, everything was fine until the end. For some reason, I get `Leaflet JavaScript library could not be detected error`. I verified that the library is uploaded inside the correct directory; `sites/all/libraries/leaflet/` but deleted and uploaded it again just in case. I spent over 2 hours to resolve it but I'd really like some help now!

Website address: http://www.kampuster.com/tr/home-inner-new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that there is an error in the code. I changed version control to the following and it worked.

```
'version' > 0
```

The version has to be added to the leaflet_libraries_info() hook.
There is an open issue in the Leaflet module [issue queue here](https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet/issues/2895968) which outlines the problem